# How to activate key bindings at runtime?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, keyboard-shortcuts

At a certain point in my RCP app I would like to offer Start, Stop, Next, Previous etc. using shortcuts such as F5, Shift+F5, Ctrl+N, Ctrl+P. These are already defined in the standard scheme and for a time I would like to override the standard actions.

Is it possible to switch the active key binding scheme at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.contexts` extension point to define a new 'context' for key bindings and then declare your key bindings in that context.

For example the Ant editor declares a context `org.eclipse.ant.ui.AntEditorScope`:

```xml
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.contexts">
   <context
         name="%context.editingAnt.name"
         description="%context.editingAnt.description"
         parentId="org.eclipse.ui.textEditorScope"
         id="org.eclipse.ant.ui.AntEditorScope">
   </context>
</extension>
```

and declares key bindings in that context:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
     <key
        sequence="M1+M2+F"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ant.ui.AntEditorScope"
        commandId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.format"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"/>
```

To use the context you must activate it. In an editor which extends `TextEditor` override `initializeKeyBindingScopes`:

```java
@Override
protected void initializeKeyBindingScopes() {
    setKeyBindingScopes(new String[] { "org.eclipse.ant.ui.AntEditorScope" }); 
}
```

Elsewhere use the `IContextService` service `activateContext` method.